# How can i use the variables (which are inside try/catch block) outside the block?

Tags: java, methods, try-catch, java.util.scanner, do-while

i am trying to use try/catch block but i can't get the variables values out of the block.
What can i do ?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
        returnValue();
        System.out.println(returnValue());
    }

    public static int returnValue() {
        Scanner imp = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean loP = true;
        do {
            String num = imp.next();
            try {
                int Nums = Integer.parseInt(num);
                loP = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a number : ");
            }
        } while (loP);
        imp.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare them outside the block, just like you've declared other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare them outside the block and give them a default value.

```
public static int returnValue(){
    Scanner imp = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean loP = true;
    int Nums =0; //declare them outside the try...catch block and give them a default value
    do {
        String num = imp.next();
        try {
           Nums = Integer.parseInt(num);
            loP = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number : ");
        }
    } while (loP);
    imp.close();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable at start of the method returnValue() with some initial value, otherwise it will show you never initialize warning and in future it will help you in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare your variables with the needed [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). For example, just declare your `Nums` variable where you declare the `loP` variable.

Answer (score 0):

use private int on the class. and update it from the try/catche section. you can able to use it from any functions.

```
public class program{
 private int something;
 public int somemorething;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
    System.out.println(returnValue());
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
    System.out.println(returnValue());
}

public static int returnValue() {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do {
        try {
            String num = bufferedReader.readLine();
            return Integer.parseInt(num);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number : ");
        }
    } while (true);
}
```